# How to cache inserted values to HashMap from different threads and insert them to db after time interval

Tags: multithreading, rx-java, rx-java2

I am learning RxJava and trying to simulate situation like this:

I have a hashMap:

```
private HashMap<String, Object> cacheToInsertToDb;
```

Suppose i put some values to it from different threads:

```
 Observable.interval(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .take(30) // up to 30 items
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(new Consumer<Long>() {
                @Override
                public void accept(Long aLong) throws Exception {
                    cacheToInsertToDb.put(aLong+"", aLong);
                    Log.d("Observable", cacheToInsertToDb.values().toString());
                }
            }, new Consumer<Throwable>() {
                @Override
                public void accept(Throwable throwable) throws Exception {

                }
            }, new Action() {
                @Override
                public void run() throws Exception {

                }
            });
```

How can i manage situtation like this in RxJava: After insert of the values from diferrent threads in time interval like 30 seconds clear the hashmap and insert values to db, all in different thread. I want to not lose any inserted values. All should be synchronized. Is it possible to do it in one query in RxJava or is it more complicated?

For now i create something like this:

```
       Observable.interval(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(new Consumer<Long>() {
                @Override
                public void accept(Long aLong) throws Exception {
                    //TODO save current values and clear
                    cacheToInsertToDb.clear();
                    Log.d("CLEARED", cacheToInsertToDb.values().toString());
                }
            }, new Consumer<Throwable>() {
                @Override
                public void accept(Throwable throwable) throws Exception {

                }
            }, new Action() {
                @Override
                public void run() throws Exception {

                }
            });
```

Comment: What is the purpose of the map? It seems you are just putting the value itself into the map. If you want to just queue a series of elements to be flushed to the DB periodically, then use the `buffer()` operator. As in, `subject.buffer(1000, 30, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)`

Comment: But can it be suitable if the elements will be trying to be inserted to db from different threads? I want to create mechanism to cache some values and to the do the actual insert to db for like 30 seconds interval. If it is possible, please show me some more specific example what do you mean in code

Comment: See my answer that I just added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two things that you need in order to get that approach to work.

The first part is using a serialized source. Create a serialized subject, by:

```
Subject<Long> source = PublishSubject.<Long>create().toSerialized();
```

Now, each of your active threads can safely use `source.onNext(value)`.

The second part is to move the caching and flushing to its own thread:

```
source
  .buffer( 30, TimeUnit.SECONDS )
  .subscribe( bufferedData -> db.write(bufferedData) );
```

`buffer()` will operate on a particular scheduler, and all downstream operations will run on that thread.

Comment: Hi again, can you tell me if there is a simple way to subscribe/unsubscribe to this source only if there are subscribers? I mean, i don't want to have this buffer runs all the time, only if there are events posted to this

Comment: How do you mean "subscribers"? There is little penalty for running the `buffer()` operator all the time. If you don't want to update when there is no data, you can add `.filter( buffer -> !buffer.isEmpty())` to not pass not invoke the `write` method.

Comment: I meant to have this buffer only running when there are threads that invoke onNext on this. I want to not be active this buffer when there are no threads that invoke on next. So for example for 10 seconds if there is none threads that invoke on next dispose this buffer

Comment: Also how can i check if this source is active? something like source.isSubscribed or something like this :)

Comment: `source` is subscribed to by the observer chain given in my answer. I can provide a new answer if you can explain why you have to dispose of the buffering step.

Comment: I have a question, when the .filter( buffer -> !buffer.isEmpty()) is true then the subject will not invoke .subscribe( bufferedData -> db.write(bufferedData) ) but also, it will be disposed/unsubscribed? I mean i don't want that to be active and taking memory

Comment: Also will be the   .subscribe( bufferedData -> db.write(bufferedData) ); invoked on different thread by default, or i just need to add  .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()) ?

Comment: 1) It will not be unsubscribed or disposed when there is no data. 2) Unsubscribing and resubscribing is more work than letting the observer chain be. 3) `buffer()` takes no more space when there is no data. 4) `buffer()` puts all work on to one thread and all subscriptions will be on that thread, unless you pass a scheduler to `buffer()` or use `observeOn()`.